# Busca automática em form utilizando dados de uma string

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma string `$numero` e ela retorna vários números.

Também tenho uma página inicial (index.php) com um form da seguinte forma:

```
<html>
<body>
<div width="100%" height="100%" align="center">

 <!-- htaccess tratando o pagina/ para pagina.php -->

  <form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="post" action="pagina/">


    <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero">
    <input type="hidden" name="inicial" id="inicial" value="S">
    <input type="hidden" name="ws" id="ws">
    <input type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="formulario.ws.value=0; submit()" />
    <input type="button" value="Consultar + webservice" onclick="formulario.ws.value=1; submit()" />
     </form>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

A página inicial tem dois botões.
Além disso, existe uma página (pagina.php) que trata a pesquisa, salva no banco de dados a busca entre outros .

Quando eu entro na index.php e preencho o número e clico no segundo botão2 (Consultar + webservice) ele retorna o que eu preciso na página.php.

Como eu faço para fazer as buscas automáticas com um espaço de tempo X utilizando a minha string `$numero`?

Ou seja, eu quero otimizar o tempo e não ter que fazer busca por busca no form da index.php, ou seja, eu quero algo automático (com espaço de tempo X) que utilize o $numero e vá fazer as buscas e salvando no banco de dados.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de fazer as buscas automáticas e ainda em um determinado tempo, se colocar  uma função igual a setInterval(function () {escopo},tempo) do Jquery irá fazer isso, mais não é recomendado pois a aplicação vai ficar usando recurso do servidor.

Comment: @HENRIQUELOBO, é que eu tenho uma relação com vários números que quero pesquisar e o webservice aceita requisições a cada 3 segundos. E eu quero otimizar para não ter que fazer 1 por 1, ou seja, preenchendo no campo e clicar em buscar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este seria um exemplo para verificar se o número está preenchido, se tiver, simula o click no seu botão que consulta o WebService. A verificação está em 60 segundos, caso deseje alterar para 4 segundos por exemplo, altere o 60000 para 4000.

```
setInterval( function(){
    var valueNumero = $('#numero').val().trim();

    if(!!valueNumero)
    {
        // Ação no primeiro botão
        // $('button[value="Consultar"]', '#formulario').click();

        // Ação no segundo botão
        $('button[value="Consultar + webservice"]', '#formulario').click();
    }

}, 60000);
```